# Application crashed when I am using PresentModelView in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, presentmodalviewcontroller

Here is my code:

```
 -(void)btnAction
  {
   mapController = [[MKMapController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MKMapController" bundle:nil];
mapController.delegate = self;
mapController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:mapController animated:YES];
[mapController release];
  }
```

I am getting the crash message as:

```
-[MKMapController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x79ccc90
```

Guy's please help me how to resolve this..!!

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

Release your `mapController` in dealloc method.

Comment: When I tap on to that button the dealloc method should call and release some of the objects there if I release this controller in dealloc the dealloc method is not called when I tap on to the button.

Comment: post your entire .m file and I will give you a solution

Comment: Sorry pls dont mind there is some secured code in that so that I can't able to share it here.

Comment: Your dealloc method shouldn't be called when btnAction is called. If you present a ModalView the ParentView won't be dealloced

Comment: @AndreasGrauel: Then wt is the solution any suggestions?

Comment: your english is too vague to understand.. but even then create a MKMapController object in the .h file and then release it in dealloc.. that is how it is done.